# Accessing XML sttribute with certain value?

Tags: php, xml-parsing

This is my XML: https://www.ecb.europa.eu/stats/eurofxref/eurofxref-daily.xml

I am loading it with the `simplexml_load_file` function, which works fine. I can also access the time attribute of the Cube node, but how can I for example get the value for the Cube node where `currency="JPY"`?

I tried several approaches, but nothing seems to do the job.

Thanks!

Comment: Looks like XPath is what you are after, have a research and then if you are still stuck then ask with what you have tried and where it is not working.

Comment: where are the codes? a simple foreach should suffice, then on each node just call `->attributes()` to expose the values you need, then it's just calling the properties of the object